# Azure export security recommendations

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-security

I am working with Azure Security Centre here, and I would like to export all security recommendations from Azure Security centre to a CSV or any sort of spreadsheet format really.

Currently, I have been working with the log search facility under the assumption that there may be a method hidden away in there, to find the security issue as an event when it was originally highlighted.  However, no success so far.

The end goal is to have a sheet with resources on the left, and any security issues noted beside them.  Has the community here encountered the same limitations with Azure Security Centre?  And if so how did you work around it?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting of security recommendations from Security Center is currently not supported and there is already a feature request available in Azure User voice - [Export to CSV](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/347535-azure-security-center/suggestions/12305691-export-to-csv).  You can also up-vote this request in User Voice for the product team to include into their plans.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update on this ASC now has a capability to export it’s findings (alerts/recommendations) to CSV as well as to Log Analytics and Events Hub.